# What is a fundamental system of neighborhoods?

Tags: general-topology

[image]

What is the definition of fundamental system of neighborhoods?

Comment: It's just the subset of the basis of the topology containing $x$.

Answer (score 1):

Presumably, it's a synonym for *neighborhood base*: A family $\mathcal N_x$ of neighborhoods of $x$ such that for every neighborhood $U$ of $x$, there exists $N \in \mathcal N_x$ with $N \subseteq U$.

Comment: It is indeed a common (European, mostly) synonym for a local base at $x$.